# Hiding Resharper files with TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

What is TortoiseGit's equivalent to TortoiseSVN's "ignore patterns" ?
Or otherwise, how do I make it ignore Resharper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have these lines in my .gitignore:

```
_ReSharper.*
*.ReSharper.user
*.resharper.user
```

Comment: In Windows Explorer you can't create a file named with what it considers only an extension. Use notepad or similar and "Save as.." to overcome that.

Answer (score 4):

I think TortoiseGit uses Git-style [Gitignore files](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.6.0.6/gitignore.html) to mark files/directories as ignored.

You may also want to consider using [Git Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions) instead of TortoiseGit.

Answer (score 2):

Just add .gitignore file to the directory that contains the files you want ignored. Inside that file list the file patterns you want excluded(one oer line). TortoiseGIT will respect those.